# Custom Console.WriteLine w/ Stream buffer

Tags: c#, console

I'm working on creating a program that involves a custom Console.WriteLine class.
I'm not importing any classes of course as I'm going for a unique design.

```
class Write {
   public static string Line(string text) {
     return text;
   }
}

public void main()
{
   Write.Line("Stuff");
}
```

I know that to make this display upon the screen, I need to access the stream buffer (or something along those lines). I'm not quite sure how I would go about doing that.

If you are going to help out, please don't give me the direct answer, I'm wanting to learn from this experience so I would like to read a documentation or something along those lines.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what do you want to do with that stream buffer? Maybe, you meant "screen buffer"?

Comment: "Give me links to documentation" is off-topic on SO. You've obviously already searched for something like https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+write+output+console+win32  - so make sure to [edit] post with results of your research and concrete problem you face implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not stream buffer but Console Screen Buffer

Please take a look at this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088(v=vs.85).aspx

you have to use this to write characters to the screen,
If you have any more difficulties I'll be happy to help further

Comment: So where exactly would I go about creating this screen buffer? @FadiBanna

Comment: in the line method instead of returning a string you should show the string on the screen using the screen buffer try that and update your post with the code you tried so we can help you further if you still have issues

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I would use the screen buffer. I can't access anything it mentioned on the site.. Do I need to import system or something? @FadiBanna

Comment: I'm guessing I would need to do this in c++? or can I Intergrate it into c#. If so how would I go about doing this? All functions is lists on the site don't explain how I would go about doing this